# preview crashing with yosemite and mavericks

Tags: macos, imac, crash, preview

I updated from 10.6.8 to yosemite and since then preview crashes every time I open an image.

I rolled back to 10.6.8 and installed mavericks and got the same problem.

Can anyone figure this out?

Here is the crash report:

```
Process:         Preview [578]
Path:            /Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview
Identifier:      com.apple.Preview
Version:         7.0 (826.4)
Build Info:      Preview-826004000000000~2
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [273]
Responsible:     Preview [578]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2015-01-07 11:42:37.801 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  xxxxxxxx-7FE8-E03B-C865-FDFDEAD50843


Crashed Thread:  3  Dispatch queue: CA::CG::Queue

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
Graphics hardware encountered an error and was reset: 0x00000000


Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff941a2a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff941a1d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff986eef15 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff986ee539 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff986ede75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff95e92a0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff95e927b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff95e925bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8cb0224e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8cb0189b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8caf599c -[NSApplication run] + 553
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8cae0783 NSApplicationMain + 940
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff96e3e5fd start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff941a2a56 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff98127451 _os_semaphore_wait + 16
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9756d982 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 310
3   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff9a42392b CABackingStoreGetFrontTexture(CABackingStore*) + 99
4   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff9a42b1e2 CABackingStorePrepareFrontTexture + 54
5   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff9a41cbd5 CA::Layer::prepare_commit(CA::Transaction*) + 371
6   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff9a418347 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 247
7   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff9a417fd6 CA::Transaction::commit() + 388
8   com.apple.imageKit              0x00007fff94dfc9bf __44-[IKImageViewLayerQueue _popBlockAndDisplay]_block_invoke + 807
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9756a1bb _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9756728d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff97569082 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9756a177 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fc9ef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fccfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff941a7662 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff97569421 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 239
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff97569136 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 3 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: CA::CG::Queue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff941a6866 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fc935c pthread_kill + 92
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff93d24b1a abort + 125
3   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib      0x00007fff941b01ca gpusKillClient + 111
4   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib      0x00007fff941b0b51 gpusQueueSubmitDataBuffers + 155
5   com.apple.AMDRadeonX3000GLDriver    0x00001234801ea050 0x123480000000 + 2007120
6   com.apple.AMDRadeonX3000GLDriver    0x00001234801e9f36 0x123480000000 + 2006838
7   com.apple.AMDRadeonX3000GLDriver    0x00001234801ea2ca gldFlushQueue + 37
8   com.apple.opencl                0x00007fff8d983a8c 0x7fff8d97d000 + 27276
9   com.apple.opencl                0x00007fff8d99fd5e clFlush + 174
10  com.apple.CoreImage             0x00007fff979fcfeb -[FEOpenCLContext(Buffer) renderUsingGPUWithRenderCallback:destinationFormat:workingFormat:extent:transform:info:] + 595
11  com.apple.CoreImage             0x00007fff978f2f33 -[CICLContextImpl renderWithBounds:matrix:function:info:] + 4590
12  com.apple.CoreImage             0x00007fff978f8109 -[CIContextImpl render:] + 230
13  com.apple.CoreImage             0x00007fff978f5988 -[CIContext render:] + 719
14  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff9a56b92d CA::OGL::CGLContext::render_ciimage(void const*, void const*, CGAffineTransform const&, bool) + 589
15  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff9a527f2f CA::CG::fill_shading(CA::CG::Renderer&, CGShading*, CA::Mat2<double> const&, bool) + 762
16  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff9a51fc68 CA::CG::DrawOp::render(CA::CG::Renderer&) const + 2770
17  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff9a530a43 CA::CG::Queue::render_callback(void*) + 293
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9756728d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff97569673 _dispatch_queue_drain + 451
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9756a9c1 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 110
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff97568f87 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 75
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9756a177 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fc9ef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fccfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff941a6e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fc9f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fccfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff941a6e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fc9f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fccfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff941a6e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fc9f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fccfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff941a6e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fc9f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fccfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff941a6e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fc9f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fccfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff941a6e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fc9f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fccfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff941a6e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fc9f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fccfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff941a6e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fc9f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fccfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff941a6e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fc9f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fccfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff941a2a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff941a1d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff986eef15 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff986ee539 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff986ede75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8cca205e _NSEventThread + 144
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fc8899 _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fc872a _pthread_start + 137
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fccfc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 14:: CVDisplayLink
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff941a6716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fcac77 _pthread_cond_wait + 787
2   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff98b61464 CVDisplayLink::waitUntil(unsigned long long) + 244
3   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff98b60998 CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 496
4   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff98b6078f startIOThread(void*) + 147
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fc8899 _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fc872a _pthread_start + 137
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff97fccfc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 3 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x000000010938b000  rcx: 0x0000000109387c68  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000002407  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x0000000109387c90  rsp: 0x0000000109387c68
   r8: 0x0000000000000002   r9: 0x00007fff93d4c8d0  r10: 0x000000000c000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x00007fa73b017400  r13: 0x0000000109387f70  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x00007fa73b017400
  rip: 0x00007fff941a6866  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fff7d8d8640

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
       0x108eec000 -        0x1090cffef  com.apple.Preview (7.0 - 826.4) <40BAB370-D0EA-399C-94E0-F67F8131AAC7> /Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview
       0x109184000 -        0x1091affff  com.apple.MediaUI (1.1 - 27) <2482C4A0-6D72-3870-AEF1-31F6015F2719> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaUI.framework/Versions/A/MediaUI
       0x10aade000 -        0x10aae6ff3  libCGCMS.A.dylib (599.35.4) <67AD122A-B8DA-3C05-8B8C-1939F5064FAE> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCGCMS.A.dylib
       0x10aaf0000 -        0x10ab18ffb  libRIP.A.dylib (599.35.4) <F3C60582-1F27-335D-9C97-8CF307670F7B> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
       0x10ab28000 -        0x10ab2bffa  libCGXType.A.dylib (599.35.4) <A2B493FD-2EDE-3BC2-A281-2381E0156411> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
       0x10dd21000 -        0x10dd27ff7  com.apple.BookKit (1.0 - 75) <4AD4969C-B6DE-3926-B723-64200A2A674B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BookKit.framework/BookKit
       0x10ded9000 -        0x10e079ff7  GLEngine (9.6.1) <EC1A6BE4-30FF-3DC4-96B9-F7F07B1FBF28> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Resources/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
       0x10e0b5000 -        0x10e0defff  GLRendererFloat (9.6.1) <DE3C5DE1-3F2F-3F3C-BC34-20EBA567A1E8> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Resources/GLRendererFloat.bundle/GLRendererFloat
       0x10e134000 -        0x10e135ff4 +cl_kernels (???) <83B72E8B-C26A-4713-BF6F-B3487D8962D6> cl_kernels
       0x10e142000 -        0x10e142ff9 +cl_kernels (???) <D30AE68E-2E9F-40CB-BA95-416FBE7659C5> cl_kernels
       0x10e144000 -        0x10e22afef  unorm8_bgra.dylib (2.3.58) <641EC871-01E8-301F-8695-B92993AD7E23> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/ImageFormats/unorm8_bgra.dylib
       0x10e701000 -        0x10e702ffa +cl_kernels (???) <52C8AAC3-9BC2-46F7-8951-2FCE02C78484> cl_kernels
    0x123480000000 -     0x12348028bff7  com.apple.AMDRadeonX3000GLDriver (1.24.38 - 1.2.4) <60773040-60AD-31C7-92F5-206F92C74EF9> /System/Library/Extensions/AMDRadeonX3000GLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AMDRadeonX3000GLDriver
    0x7fff67d3b000 -     0x7fff67d6e817  dyld (239.4) <7AD43B9B-5CEA-3C7E-9836-A06909F9CA56> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff8c8fb000 -     0x7fff8c94cfff  com.apple.QuickLookFramework (5.0 - 622.7) <17685CEC-C94B-3F83-ADE1-B24840B35E44> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/Versions/A/QuickLook
    0x7fff8c99f000 -     0x7fff8ca90ff9  libiconv.2.dylib (41) <BB44B115-AC32-3877-A0ED-AEC6232A4563> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    0x7fff8ca91000 -     0x7fff8ca99fff  libMatch.1.dylib (19) <021293AB-407D-309A-87F5-8E782F46753E> /usr/lib/libMatch.1.dylib
    0x7fff8ca9a000 -     0x7fff8caa9ff8  com.apple.LangAnalysis (1.7.0 - 1.7.0) <8FE131B6-1180-3892-98F5-C9C9B79072D4> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
    0x7fff8caaa000 -     0x7fff8cab2ff7  com.apple.AppleSRP (5.0 - 1) <ABC7F088-1FD5-3768-B9F3-847F355E90B3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSRP.framework/Versions/A/AppleSRP
    0x7fff8cade000 -     0x7fff8d654ff7  com.apple.AppKit (6.9 - 1265.21) <9DC13B27-841D-3839-93B2-3EDE66157BDE> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    0x7fff8d658000 -     0x7fff8d659ff7  libSystem.B.dylib (1197.1.1) <70B235FC-BCED-367B-BA6C-67C299BAE7D9> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff8d66d000 -     0x7fff8d6e0fff  com.apple.securityfoundation (6.0 - 55122.3) <0FDC8F53-104C-3938-A852-5B33C30BAAD5> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
    0x7fff8d6ee000 -     0x7fff8d75bfff  com.apple.SearchKit (1.4.0 - 1.4.0) <B9B8D510-A27E-36B0-93E9-17146D9E9045> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
    0x7fff8d75c000 -     0x7fff8d767fff  libkxld.dylib (2422.115.4) <3C678B75-F7C5-3DBB-8DBD-48483AD54D5C> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
    0x7fff8d84c000 -     0x7fff8d93afff  libJP2.dylib (1044) <BE5FF765-5ECE-38B5-BF5D-BE806F5CAD18> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJP2.dylib
    0x7fff8d97d000 -     0x7fff8d9cbff7  com.apple.opencl (2.3.59 - 2.3.59) <9F43F471-C3C3-352D-889D-EC418DC1F5B2> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
    0x7fff8d9cc000 -     0x7fff8d9cdffb  libremovefile.dylib (33) <3543F917-928E-3DB2-A2F4-7AB73B4970EF> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff8d9ce000 -     0x7fff8dc32ffd  com.apple.security (7.0 - 55471.14.18) <83A9E8C8-06A1-3F6D-8514-C35CD0DBD370> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
    0x7fff8dc33000 -     0x7fff8dc3affb  libcopyfile.dylib (103.92.1) <CF29DFF6-0589-3590-834C-82E2316612E8> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff8dc3b000 -     0x7fff8de99ff2  com.apple.RawCamera.bundle (5.06 - 753) <7315ED29-77A1-3990-9054-F00B96527C06> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/Contents/MacOS/RawCamera
    0x7fff8dec4000 -     0x7fff8df95fff  com.apple.QuickLookUIFramework (5.0 - 622.7) <13841701-34C2-353D-868D-3E08D020C90F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QuickLookUI.framework/Versions/A/QuickLookUI
    0x7fff8dfee000 -     0x7fff8e016ffb  libxslt.1.dylib (13) <C9794936-633C-3F0C-9E71-30190B9B41C1> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
    0x7fff8e017000 -     0x7fff8e465fef  com.apple.VideoToolbox (1.0 - 1273.54) <4699BB55-7387-3981-9217-869215F00CA9> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/Versions/A/VideoToolbox
    0x7fff8e466000 -     0x7fff8e490ff7  libsandbox.1.dylib (278.11.1) <40E0FA20-43F4-3B44-8FB7-E070170E9AB9> /usr/lib/libsandbox.1.dylib
    0x7fff8e491000 -     0x7fff8e791ff7  com.apple.Foundation (6.9 - 1056.16) <24349208-3603-3F5D-95CC-B379616FBEF8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff8e84c000 -     0x7fff8e857ff7  com.apple.NetAuth (5.0 - 5.0) <C811E662-9EC3-3B74-808A-A75D624F326B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetAuth.framework/Versions/A/NetAuth
    0x7fff8e858000 -     0x7fff8e86bff7  com.apple.AppContainer (3.0 - 1) <BD342039-430E-39FE-BC2D-8F97B557548E> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppContainer.framework/Versions/A/AppContainer
    0x7fff8e86c000 -     0x7fff8e8c7ffb  com.apple.AE (665.5 - 665.5) <BBA230F9-144C-3CAB-A77A-0621719244CD> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
    0x7fff8e8c8000 -     0x7fff8e8f7ff9  com.apple.GSS (4.0 - 2.0) <44E914BE-B0D0-3E05-9451-CA9E539AFA52> /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/Versions/A/GSS
    0x7fff8e8f8000 -     0x7fff8e927fff  com.apple.DebugSymbols (106 - 106) <E1BDED08-523A-36F4-B2DA-9D5C712F0AC7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DebugSymbols.framework/Versions/A/DebugSymbols
    0x7fff8e928000 -     0x7fff8e929fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (278.11.1) <0D0B13EA-6B7A-3AC8-BE60-B548543BEB77> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff8e92a000 -     0x7fff8e999ff1  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS (360 - 363.3) <546E89D9-2AE7-3111-B2B8-2366650D22F0> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
    0x7fff8f2b3000 -     0x7fff8f304ff7  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio (4.2.1 - 4.2.1) <BE13E840-FB45-3BC2-BCF5-031629754FD5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
    0x7fff8f305000 -     0x7fff8f30dfff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (522.92.1) <3F8C6A07-3046-3E88-858F-D9CEFC43A405> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff8f329000 -     0x7fff8f3aafff  com.apple.CoreSymbolication (3.0.1 - 141.0.5) <82170C9C-73E0-3108-9DC5-C214C9B72292> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSymbolication.framework/Versions/A/CoreSymbolication
    0x7fff8f3ab000 -     0x7fff8f40ffff  com.apple.datadetectorscore (5.0 - 354.5) <C9FAB401-3FE2-3221-B60C-E4F1841CA5F1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/Versions/A/DataDetectorsCore
    0x7fff8f410000 -     0x7fff8f4c0ff7  libvMisc.dylib (423.32) <049C0735-1808-39B9-943F-76CB8021744F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
    0x7fff8f4c1000 -     0x7fff8f4c1ffd  libOpenScriptingUtil.dylib (157) <19F0E769-0989-3062-9AFB-8976E90E9759> /usr/lib/libOpenScriptingUtil.dylib
    0x7fff8f4c2000 -     0x7fff8f4c4ff7  com.apple.securityhi (9.0 - 55005) <9985032A-0EE1-3760-8D23-ADD3965A4D18> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SecurityHI.framework/Versions/A/SecurityHI
    0x7fff8f4c5000 -     0x7fff8f4c8fff  com.apple.help (1.3.3 - 46) <AE763646-D07A-3F9A-ACD4-F5CBD734EE36> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Help.framework/Versions/A/Help
    0x7fff8f4e9000 -     0x7fff8f510ff7  libsystem_network.dylib (241.3) <8B1E1F1D-A5CC-3BAE-8B1E-ABC84337A364> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff8f511000 -     0x7fff8f5d5ff7  com.apple.backup.framework (1.5.4 - 1.5.4) <195DA868-47A5-37E6-8CF0-9BCF11846899> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Backup.framework/Versions/A/Backup
    0x7fff8f5d6000 -     0x7fff8f624fff  libcorecrypto.dylib (161.1) <F3973C28-14B6-3006-BB2B-00DD7F09ABC7> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff8f625000 -     0x7fff8f6adff7  com.apple.CorePDF (4.0 - 4) <92D15ED1-D2E1-3ECB-93FF-42888219A99F> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CorePDF.framework/Versions/A/CorePDF
    0x7fff8f6db000 -     0x7fff8f80afef  com.apple.MediaControlSender (2.0 - 200.34.4) <FC24EC8D-2E46-3F76-AF63-749F30857B96> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/Versions/A/MediaControlSender
    0x7fff8f826000 -     0x7fff8f90aff7  com.apple.coreui (2.2 - 231.1) <187DF89C-8A64-366D-8782-F90315FA3CD7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
    0x7fff8f997000 -     0x7fff8f9d0ff7  com.apple.QD (3.50 - 298) <C1F20764-DEF0-34CF-B3AB-AB5480D64E66> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
    0x7fff8f9d1000 -     0x7fff8f9d1fff  com.apple.Carbon (154 - 157) <45A9A40A-78FF-3EA0-8FAB-A4F81052FA55> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
    0x7fff8f9d2000 -     0x7fff8f9edff7  libsystem_malloc.dylib (23.10.1) <A695B4E4-38E9-332E-A772-29D31E3F1385> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff8fa2b000 -     0x7fff8fa33ff7  com.apple.speech.recognition.framework (4.2.4 - 4.2.4) <98BBB3E4-6239-3EF1-90B2-84EA0D3B8D61> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
    0x7fff8fab5000 -     0x7fff8fadfff7  libpcap.A.dylib (42) <91D3FF51-D6FE-3C05-98C9-1182E0EC3D58> /usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib
    0x7fff8fae0000 -     0x7fff8fae4fff  com.apple.IOAccelerator (98.23 - 98.23) <A5174BEC-A27D-34D8-AB7B-B86962FFAEBA> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/Versions/A/IOAccelerator
    0x7fff8fb17000 -     0x7fff8fbe2fff  libvDSP.dylib (423.32) <3BF732BE-DDE0-38EB-8C54-E4E3C64F77A7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
    0x7fff8fbe3000 -     0x7fff8fd51ff7  libBLAS.dylib (1094.5) <DE93A590-5FA5-32A2-A16C-5D7D7361769F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff8fdde000 -     0x7fff8fdf4fff  com.apple.CoreMediaAuthoring (2.2 - 947) <F1886A05-1C29-3F88-88C0-4A1013530AD1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMediaAuthoring.framework/Versions/A/CoreMediaAuthoring
    0x7fff8fdf5000 -     0x7fff8fe19fff  com.apple.quartzfilters (1.8.0 - 1.7.0) 

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 1
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 375
    thread_create: 1
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=205.5M resident=101.0M(49%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=104.5M(51%)
Writable regions: Total=235.8M written=27.8M(12%) resident=65.9M(28%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=169.9M(72%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
CG backing stores                   452K
CG image                            180K
CG raster data                     2296K
CG shared images                    180K
CoreAnimation                      4364K
CoreImage                          11.7M
Foundation                            4K
IOKit                              44.1M
IOKit (reserved)                    256K        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Image IO                           11.6M
Kernel Alloc Once                     8K
MALLOC                            137.8M
MALLOC (admin)                       32K
Memory Tag 242                       12K
Memory Tag 251                       28K
OpenCL                               32K
OpenGL GLSL                        1664K
STACK GUARD                        56.1M
Stack                              14.7M
VM_ALLOCATE                        17.0M
__DATA                             26.0M
__IMAGE                             528K
__LINKEDIT                         67.0M
__TEXT                            138.6M
__UNICODE                           544K
mapped file                        51.1M
shared memory                        68K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             586.0M
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space    585.7M


Model: iMac11,3, BootROM IM112.0057.B00, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.93 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 1.59f2
Graphics: ATI Radeon HD 5750, ATI Radeon HD 5750, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334348302D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334348302D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM1, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334348302D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM1, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334348302D4348392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x168C, 0x8F), Atheros 9280: 4.0.74.0-P2P
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.7f3 14616, 3 services, 23 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet 2, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD TS256B, 251 GB
Serial ATA Device: OPTIARC DVD RW AD-5680H
Serial ATA Device: WDC WD1001FALS-40Y6A0, 1 TB
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: DataTraveler 2.0
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: WIBU-BOX/U
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Comment: For me, it crashes everytime when I try to search in large text PDFs, it's really neat app, but this is just irritating.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me once. Have you used 'Text' tool from the markup toolbar? If so, the font you used before might not be available with your current setup.

If you remember which font it was, install it. Preview.app should open fine after.