# Mac preview crash everytime when searching

Tags: mac, pdf, crash, preview, bug

I would like to ask if you encountered similar error, and what have you done to solve it. 
 When I open multiple PDF files in Preview ( mainly text), and then search for some common substring like building, typing firstly b, then u, then i, then l, and usually preview crashes after typing 4-5 characters. 
 I emphasize I have opened 10-13 pdfs,(one is max 2 pages long), and it crashes **everytime** when I try to search by aforementioned method. Has it happened to you and how did you solve it? I submited a bug report to apple anyway.

EDIT: added code

```
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSOutlineView', reason: 'NSOutlineView error removing child indexes <NSIndexSet: 0x7fbbe99f08c0>[number of indexes: 1 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (11)] in parent 0x0 (which has 11 children).'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called
```

I tried to reinstall preview using this guide https://superuser.com/questions/835035/preview-app-always-crashes?newreg=a67db93698f84d459728455bb530cad9  from fresh Yosemite installation, without any result, it still crashes.

**EDIT:** Seems like this is not only related to text searching:
[preview crashing with yosemite and mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/166296/preview-crashing-with-yosemite-and-mavericks)

Comment: what does the crash reports ? or no report ?

Comment: The first step is always to trash the Preferences file, whatever the app, as they do become corrupt. Then install a fresh copy.

Comment: Someone on the Apple support forum suggested enclosing the search in quotes. Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a symptom of a corrupted Spotlight index.  You can rebuild your Spotlight index using Apple's instructions:

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716

Just realize that it can take a while to rebuild depending on how many files you have on your hard drive(s).

Comment: How exactly would this resolve Preview's search function?! It's not crashing due to spotlight, it's crashing due to the Find function in Preview!

Comment: It's probably crashing due to a corrupt Spotlight index. The NSOutlineView has trouble getting the relevant data (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/). Rebuild the Spotlight index would be my recommendation.