# Preview crashes (beachball) when searching pdfs? Wants to save changes to multiple docs?

Tags: crash, preview

Preview has recently started hanging when I search pdf documents, which is really hindering my work. I get the beachball for a minute before it says it's 'saving changes' to multiple documents - even though there is only one document open (see image). Any idea?

[image]

I followed the advice in [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167465/mac-preview-crash-everytime-when-searching) to no avail.